# @@ROWCOUNT Returns Inconsistent Results On Linked Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server, rowcount

When running select/update statements against a linked server (Oracle) I am getting inconsistent results in @@ROWCOUNT.

```
SELECT * FROM [LS]..[OWNER].[TABLE] WHERE [KEY] = 'X'

UPDATE [LS]..[OWNER].[TABLE] SET [COL] = 'VALUE' WHERE [KEY] = 'X'
```

The SELECT returns the 2 rows that are physically in the DB and @@ROWCOUNT=2.

The UPDATE returns @@ROWCOUNT=4.

I would expect the UPDATE to return the same @@ROWCOUNT value (2) as the select, but I must be missing something. Any thoughts?

I had planned on using the @@ROWCOUNT return values to make sure that all outstanding records were in fact updated (without having to do a 3rd SELECT) - but if this is not something I can correct, I'll have to come up with plan B.

Comment: `Table` probably has an update trigger on it, e.g.: doing logging, that doesn't include a `SET FEEDBACK OFF` statement so is emitting 2 rows for every table row getting updated.

Comment: Thanks AlwaysLearning - that makes perfect sense. I've reached out to the Oracle DBA to find out if that is in fact what is happening.

Comment: AlwaysLearning - so the DBA team for Oracle has responded that there are no triggers on the table in question, and to make things more interesting - when they run the update command on their side - they get the expected (2 rows updated) message. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Maybe a bug in the Microsoft's PL-SQL driver? What happens if you execute the update inside an `OPENQUERY()` and return Oracle's `SQL%ROWCOUNT` at the end of that statement?

Comment: I thought of that too, but we are using the Oracle driver and it seems that there is only one take displaying this behavior. I'm going to download Oracle Client and see if I can poke around the DB a bit.